# C# WPF Use points to make a stroke in the ink canvas

Tags: wpf, points

I want to use a group of points to make a stroke in the ink canvas. How to convert `StylusPointCollection` or points into `StrokeCollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually mean `Stroke`?

You can simply use [the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522848%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `Stroke` to convert from `StylusPointCollection`.

```
public Stroke (
    StylusPointCollection stylusPoints
)
```

Comment: yeah that works ! I'm new on C#, I know what i want ,but don't know how to write! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Benny Ae, welcome to Stack Overflow, and remember to accept my answer by clicking (invisible) check mark on the left of my answer. ^-^